How to determine if a race course is fair (on the open water)?
I am analyzing the distribution of race results using statistical methods like chi-square tests to look for the most uniformly distributed results. I have data from a number of different locations and configurations and I'm trying to find which course is most "fair" to any given lane assuming equal competitors.
Here's what I hope to learn by asking for help on this topic:

Is this a good technique to use for this data and goal?
Is there some better method? Or are their issues with the data set?
How do I interpret the results? (e.g. Just compare chi-squared/p-values? Does the heat map just confuse things?)

Say you're given a race course with lanes 1-8 on the water and it is suspected that some lanes are faster than others (current, wind, advantages, etc.). Faster lanes would have more higher places (1st, 2nd, etc.). Let's say you run 100 events but there's not enough competitors to fill the course so for simplicity the event is filled from lane 1 out until the event is full. Most events are rarely full so there's less data for the outer lanes, which could be a problem with this analysis.
Assume competitors are placed randomly on the course from lane 1 outwards and not selected by ability.
Using some random data with python to simulate races with uniform probability based on a typical set of races with some events lacking samples from each lane.
# random data (as an example)
random_data = {
    'lane_1': np.random.choice(range(1, 9), 92, p=[1/8]*8).tolist(),
    'lane_2': np.random.choice(range(1, 9), 93, p=[1/8]*8).tolist(),
    'lane_3': np.random.choice(range(1, 9), 91, p=[1/8]*8).tolist(),
    'lane_4': np.random.choice(range(1, 9), 90, p=[1/8]*8).tolist(),
    'lane_5': np.random.choice(range(1, 9), 88, p=[1/8]*8).tolist(),
    'lane_6': np.random.choice(range(1, 9), 76, p=[1/8]*8).tolist(),
    'lane_7': np.random.choice(range(1, 9), 64, p=[1/8]*8).tolist(),
    'lane_8': np.random.choice(range(1, 9), 34, p=[1/8]*8).tolist()
}

Assume competitors are placed randomly on the course from lane 1 outwards and not selected by ability.
So lane 1 gets 92 events (there are some disqualifications that remove competitors), lane 2 93... etc. Here's what an example heat map would look like.

and here's the Chi-Square results for this uniformly random example:
Chi-squared: 55.82543521120111
p-value: 0.23376772081410768
Degrees of freedom: 49

As a comparison here's the data vs an expected frequency heat map from applying a chi-squared test.

Now when I run this with real data
data = {
    '1': {'1': 37, '2': 17, '3': 10, '4': 12, '5': 11, '6': 3, '7': 2, 'dq': 1},
    '2': {'1': 16, '2': 31, '3': 19, '4': 8, '5': 5, '6': 9, '7': 3, 'dq': 2},
    '3': {'1': 15, '2': 16, '3': 21, '4': 15, '5': 9, '6': 7, '7': 4, '8': 3, 'dq': 1},
    '4': {'1': 10, '2': 11, '3': 22, '4': 17, '5': 17, '6': 8, '7': 4, 'dq': 1},
    '5': {'1': 4, '2': 10, '3': 9, '4': 23, '5': 18, '6': 10, '7': 8, '8': 5, 'dq': 1},
    '6': {'1': 5, '2': 6, '3': 5, '4': 5, '5': 14, '6': 15, '7': 13, '8': 8},
    '7': {'1': 6, '2': 5, '3': 8, '4': 7, '5': 11, '6': 9, '7': 13, '8': 5},
    '8': {'1': 1, '2': 1, '4': 2, '5': 1, '6': 10, '7': 12, '8': 17}
}

and compute some poor chi-squared results:
Chi-squared: 311.8435818023394
p-value: 3.446800747358413e-37
Degrees of freedom: 56



EDIT: I experimented with a Mixed mode model, but was unable to get the random data to ever converge. The random data, I'm using as a control for the null hypothesis.  I would feel better about the results if I could compare all the cases to it. The measured data was also a little difficult. I had to choose a "Position ~ Lane" model which I summarize:

First Model (89 observations, 13 groups):
Intercept: The estimated intercept is 3.595, with a standard error of 0.699. The z-value of 5.147 indicates that the intercept is

significantly different from zero, with a p-value less than 0.05. The
95% confidence interval for the intercept ranges from 2.226 to 4.964.
Lane: The coefficient for Lane is 0.323, with a standard error of 0.106. The z-value of 3.053 indicates that the coefficient is significantly different from zero, with a p-value less than 0.05. The
95% confidence interval for the coefficient ranges from 0.116 to
0.531.
Group Variance: The estimated group variance is 0.000, with a standard error of 0.315.
Second Model (628 observations, 8 groups):
Intercept: The estimated intercept is 2.565, with a standard error of 1.815. The z-value of 1.414 indicates that the intercept is not

significantly different from zero at the 0.05 level. The 95%
confidence interval for the intercept ranges from -0.992 to 6.122.
Lane (T.2 to T.8): These coefficients represent the difference in Position between each lane and the reference category (in this case,
Lane 1). None of the coefficients for Lane are statistically
significant at the 0.05 level, as indicated by their p-values being
greater than 0.05.
Group Variance: The estimated group variance is 3.258.
Comparing the two models, the first model with 89 observations and 13
groups shows significant effects for both the intercept and the Lane
variable. In contrast, the second model with 628 observations and 8
groups shows no significant effect for Lane. Additionally, the group
variance is higher in the second model, suggesting more variability in
Position within groups.

Raw Model summaries for the 2 races: 13 lanes and 8 lane courses
         Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
=======================================================
Model:            MixedLM Dependent Variable: Position 
No. Observations: 89      Method:             REML     
No. Groups:       13      Scale:              8.1821   
Min. group size:  1       Log-Likelihood:     -220.5366
Max. group size:  10      Converged:          Yes      
Mean group size:  6.8                                  
--------------------------------------------------------
           Coef.  Std.Err.    z    P>|z|  [0.025  0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------
Intercept  3.595     0.699  5.147  0.000   2.226   4.964
Lane       0.323     0.106  3.053  0.002   0.116   0.531
Group Var  0.000     0.315                              
=======================================================


         Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
========================================================
Model:            MixedLM Dependent Variable: Position  
No. Observations: 628     Method:             REML      
No. Groups:       8       Scale:              3.2580    
Min. group size:  44      Log-Likelihood:     -1263.2382
Max. group size:  92      Converged:          Yes       
Mean group size:  78.5                                  
---------------------------------------------------------
            Coef.  Std.Err.    z    P>|z|  [0.025  0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------
Intercept   2.565     1.815  1.414  0.158  -0.992   6.122
Lane[T.2]   0.369     2.567  0.144  0.886  -4.662   5.399
Lane[T.3]   0.868     2.567  0.338  0.735  -4.162   5.899
Lane[T.4]   1.109     2.567  0.432  0.666  -3.922   6.140
Lane[T.5]   1.906     2.567  0.743  0.458  -3.125   6.937
Lane[T.6]   2.604     2.569  1.014  0.311  -2.430   7.638
Lane[T.7]   2.247     2.570  0.875  0.382  -2.789   7.283
Lane[T.8]   4.162     2.574  1.617  0.106  -0.883   9.207
Group Var   3.258                                        
========================================================


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model

Rejecting the hypothesis that lanes are allocated at random seems plausible.  Lane 8 commonly seems to be used by slower boats, and something similar seems to happen for lanes 7, 6, and 5 too

I do not see why the expected frequencies for positions for row/lane 8 should vary; the question seems to suggest there are always 8 competitors when lane 8 is used. Assuming lanes are filled in ascending order, the real data looks as if you have 2 races with two boats, 1 with three boats, 2 with four boats, 17 with five boats, 7 with six boats, 20 with seven boats, and 44 with 8 boats, making 93 races in total. This is not quite right as you have 94 first places, 97 second places, 94 third places, etc. so perhaps there are ties and perhaps some early lanes are sometimes empty.

@Henry the assumption is that anyone could be put in any lane. Events were randomly (supposedly) filled from lane 1 outwards to save time between heats. So the outer lanes see less races and have less samples to compare.

@Henry The data is just a list of place counts for each lane. You could have 8 racers in all 8 lanes and only get 7 results because of a disqualification for example.

One of my points is that lane 1 is used 93 times (so too is lane 2), but somebody wins 94 times and somebody comes second 97 times.  Disqualification does not explain this anomaly.
